# AdmobFree interstitial.show() - ERROR: interstitial not ready yet

Tags: ionic2, admob

I first call

```
this.admobFree.interstitial.prepare()
    .then(() => {
      this.interstitialPrepared = true;
      console.log('AdMob Interstitial Ad is prepared, will be presented if autoShow is true, otherwise, call showInterstitial().');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    })
```

And `this.interstitialPrepared = true;` is called so I assume my ad is ready.

But if I call `this.admobFree.interstitial.show()` after my `this.interstitialPrepared` var switch to `true`, I still have the following error "ERROR: interstitial not ready yet.".

**Notice :** 
It works well with the following config  :

```
this.adMobProvider.interstitialConfig = {
        autoShow: false,
        isTesting : true
};
```

But not when I want to test with real ads

```
this.adMobProvider.interstitialConfig = {
        autoShow: false,
        isTesting : false,
        id:"ca-app-pub-277368299xxxxxxxx"
};
```

Comment: You need to receive the admob adLoaded callback before trying to show the ad. Test ad might work since its embedded in the code and available immediately

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I did this way:

1. I did not put the `interstitial.show()` after `interstitial.prepare().then(..)`;
2. I subscribed these events: `INTERSTITIAL_LOAD` and `INTERSTITIAL_LOAD_FAIL`;
3. I only showed it loaded successfully;

Example:

> ```
> this.admobFree.on(this.admobFree.events.INTERSTITIAL_LOAD).subscribe(() => {
>      this.admobFree.interstitial.show().then(() => {
>           // Show successful
>      }).catch((errorShow) => {
>           // ...
>      });
> });
>
> this.admobFree.on(this.admobFree.events.INTERSTITIAL_LOAD_FAIL).subscribe(() => {
>      // ...
> });
> ```

I hope to help you.

Answer (score -1):

In my case `autoShow: true`worked for me. Remember when autoShow is true you don't need to call the intersit